# Facebook Page Permission Query

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The problem is

1. On a Facebook Page Tab we want to show details of all the other global pages
2. This includes Name and Total Likes for the page

I have a user set up currently which has admin rights over all the pages, the access token is that of the user with offline permissions set for each page too; hard coded into an FQL query

The issue with this is if the user changes password - then this access token is invalidated.

I know it is possible to get a new one assigned - but with the new requirement to also set Manage_Page to access page information is there a better solution

ie one user with manage permissions over mutiple pages able to do one FQL call to get the required information for multiple pages.

Cheers

Ian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are getting data on Facebook Fan Pages, then getting information like name and total likes can be done without a token as that information is public.

For example:

- One Page - https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552
- Multiple Pages - https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=19292868552,11239244970

Multiple Pages Request as a Facebook JavaScript SDK Example:

```
FB.api(
    '/', 
    {ids : "19292868552,11239244970"}, 
    function(response) { 
        if (!response || response.error) {
            console.log(response.error); 
        } else { 
            console.log(response); 
        } 
    }
);
```

Initialising the JavaScript SDK with user session data - for accessing restricted page data:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : <your-app-id>,
    session : { "uid":"<users facebook id>", "access_token":"<valid access token>"},
    cookie : true, 
    xfbml  : true
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Star answer - thanks Arjuna also. I did know this but what i was trying was not giving the likes for some reason.

Comment: One query - how would I represent this Graph API call with the JS SDK?

            FB.api('/', {ids : IDs.join(',')}, function(response)
            {
                if (!response || response.error) {
                    console.log(response.error);
                } else {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });

Comment: Ok the issue I am faceing I think is that the pages I am requesting info off are Restricted by Type = alchohol. So I may need to loop through the IDS and get the info as the access token will be different for each page - any advice on this?

Comment: If a page has a restriction then you need to have an access token for a user that beats that restriction. I would suggest that you initialise the JavaScript SDK with valid user session data.

Comment: In the end I created a Test User and used the accessToken from this user to access the restricted pages data. This means my account user can now change there password at will. Thanks for the help on this.